# Excel's SubTotal Type Calculations for each of distinct number in each variable using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
structure(list(V3 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L), V4 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V5 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), V6 = c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), V7 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V8 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V9 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), V10 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L), V11 = c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), V12 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V13 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V14 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), V15 = c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L
), V16 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V17 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), V18 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), V19 = c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), V20 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V21 = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), V22 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to do is to sum the unique values in each column so that finally i should get a dataframe like this:

```
Var    0   1   2   3   4   5

V3     0   1   10  60  4   10
V4     0   1   4   66  20  5
... and so forth
```

Basically,

- there are 4 times 0 value appeared in V3, so sum will still be zero,
- while there is 1 appearance of 1 and hence sum will be 1,
- 5 times 2 appeared so sum will be 10,
- 20 times 3 appeared so sum will be 60
- 2 times 5 appeared so sum will be 10

and so forth for the rest variables.

How can it be done using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**
could shorten the code a bit

```
library(data.table)
# Melt to long
DT <- melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = names(df))
# Summarise and cast to wide
dcast(DT, variable ~ value, fun.aggregate = sum, fill = NA)
```

**original answer (also working)**

```
library(data.table)
# Melt to long
DT <- melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = names(df))
# Summarise and cast to wide
dcast(DT[, .(sum = .N * value), by = .(variable, value)], 
      variable ~ value, value.var = "sum")

#    variable 0  1  2  3  4  5
# 1:       V3 0  1 10 60  4 10
# 2:       V4 0  1  4 66 20  5
# 3:       V5 0 NA 10 57 20 10
# 4:       V6 0  2 18 54  4  5
# 5:       V7 0 NA 16 54  4  5
# 6:       V8 0  3 12 48  8 NA
# 7:       V9 0  1 14 54 20  5
# 8:      V10 0  5 16 39 16  5
# 9:      V11 0  2  2 66 20 10
#10:      V12 0  1  6 66 16 NA
#11:      V13 0  2 10 48 32 NA
#12:      V14 0  1  2 63 24 10
#13:      V15 0 NA  4 63 24  5
#14:      V16 0 NA 12 63  8 10
#15:      V17 0  2 14 45 20 10
#16:      V18 0  1  2 63 16 10
#17:      V19 0  1  8 54 16 10
#18:      V20 0  1  8 54 20  5
#19:      V21 0  1  4 57 20 10
#20:      V22 0  1  6 63 16  5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = value, values_from = value, values_fn = sum)

# A tibble: 20 x 7
   name    `0`   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 V8        0     3    12    48     8    NA
 2 V18       0     1     2    63    16    10
 3 V19       0     1     8    54    16    10
 4 V20       0     1     8    54    20     5
 5 V21       0     1     4    57    20    10
 6 V3        0     1    10    60     4    10
 7 V4        0     1     4    66    20     5
 8 V5        0    NA    10    57    20    10
 9 V6        0     2    18    54     4     5
10 V7        0    NA    16    54     4     5
11 V9        0     1    14    54    20     5
12 V10       0     5    16    39    16     5
13 V11       0     2     2    66    20    10
14 V12       0     1     6    66    16    NA
15 V13       0     2    10    48    32    NA
16 V14       0     1     2    63    24    10
17 V15       0    NA     4    63    24     5
18 V16       0    NA    12    63     8    10
19 V17       0     2    14    45    20    10
20 V22       0     1     6    63    16     5
```

Comment: something goes wrong here. in the sample data provided, there is no occurence of V5 with value 1. Yet your output is 10..

Comment: yes, I saw the error. try using `tidyverse`

Comment: @Wimpel - nevermind the data, i just provided a sample of larger dataset where we have many counts of each. Thanks very much for your help.